# Prevent Cplex setting to NaN coefficients of problem variables, exception 1225 is thrown on problem modify attempt

Tags: c++, cplex

I'm coding and a branch-and-price algorithm and the problem arises when, after having added some cuts to the restricted master problem (RMP), I try to add some further columns.
On creating an `IloNumVar` object from an instance of `IloNumColumn` for the new column to add, I get exception 1225 with message "Numeric entry is not a double precision number (NAN)".
It seems coming form the slack variables that I have in the equality constraints for the RMP feasibility and column generation.
The problem disappear if I use smaller values for the slack variables' objective function (OF) coefficients, but this impair the branching because I need a sufficiently large value.
Cplex usually manages well variables with much larger OF coefficient.

It seems to be a bug that arises on attempt of problem modification.
I did not find any Cplex useful documentation for this issue.

Anyone experienced this issue and/or have any solution/workaround?

Many thanks in advance.